# A one-liner to convert list of tuples to two lists?

Tags: python

As above.
Example:

```
a = [('P', 2), ('J, 3'), ('K', 3)]
```

Required:
b = ['P', 'J',  'K']
and c = [2, 3, 3]

Comment: Check the first answer in the duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
b, c = zip(*the_thing)
```

Example:

```
>>> b, c = zip(*[('P', 2), ('J', 3), ('K', 3)])
>>> b
('P', 'J', 'K')
>>> c
(2, 3, 3)
```

Comment: Okay, that is genuis. Some explanation? Zip takes in lists or iterables in general, right?

Comment: @AlexDeft, the thing is, it can take [_multiple_ iterables](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip). The asterisk (`*`) unpacks the list into multiple arguments, and then `zip` zips them. BTW, the answer to your question is in the last paragraph of the section about `zip` in the docs)

Comment: One last question, zip returns a zip object. Shouldn't we do this: list(zip(...)) and then unpack it?

Comment: @AlexDeft, the zip object is iterable, so you can loop over it and use the `x, y, z = iterable` syntax.